# Find function with highest value with defined x value

Tags: python

I want to find the function with the highest value with a defined x.

I have defined multiple mathematical functions. I can plot everyone of them. Now i want a python-function to tell me what function has the highest value with a given x (e.g. x=1).

```
parable=x**2
linear=3*x
sine=np.sin(x)
```

Result for x=1 should be "linear" and for x = 4 the result should be "parable".

Comment: Do you just want the value or do you need to know which function?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp

Comment: You compute the functional values and compare them.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to name the variables and find the max of the values.

```
x = 1
d = {'parable' : parable(x), 'linear' : linear(x), 'sine' : sine(x)}
print(max(d, key=d.get))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the functions in a dictionary and use the `max()` function.

```
funs = {"parable": lambda x: x**2, "linear": lambda x: 3*x, "sine": lambda x: np.sin(x)}
def highest_fun(x):
    return max(funs, key = lambda f: funs[f](x))
print(highest_fun(1))
print(highest_fun(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe several function return the same (highest) value. In that case, I would propose this solution:

```
import numpy as np
funcs = {"linear" :lambda x: 3*x, "parable": lambda x: x**2, "sine": lambda x: np.sin(x)}
x = 1
res = {key:val(x) for key, val in funcs.items()}
maximum = max(res.values())
highest = [key for key, val in res.items() if val==maximum]
```

This saves all the maximum functions in the list `highest`. You could print it with

```
print(", ".join(highest) + " is/are the function(s) with the highest value: %d" %(maximum))
```

For example with `x = 0` it prints:

`linear, parable, sine is/are the function(s) with the highest value: 0`

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` solution:

Since you need all the values for plotting anyway, you can keep them a while longer and use `numpy` to efficiently compute the maximum values and their corresponding functions with `numpy.select`.

Demo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(10) # dummy values for demo                                                                                                           
>>> parable=x**2                                                                                                                  
>>> linear=3*x                                                                                                                    
>>> sine=np.sin(x)                                                                                                                
>>>                                                                                                                               
>>> values = np.c_[parable, linear, sine]                                                                                         
>>> values                                                                                                                        
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  3.        ,  0.84147098],
       [ 4.        ,  6.        ,  0.90929743],
       [ 9.        ,  9.        ,  0.14112001],
       [16.        , 12.        , -0.7568025 ],
       [25.        , 15.        , -0.95892427],
       [36.        , 18.        , -0.2794155 ],
       [49.        , 21.        ,  0.6569866 ],
       [64.        , 24.        ,  0.98935825],
       [81.        , 27.        ,  0.41211849]])
>>> argmaxes = values.argmax(axis=1) 
>>> argmaxes                                                                                                        
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> np.select([argmaxes == 0, argmaxes == 1, argmaxes == 2], ['parable', 'linear', 'sine'])                                       
array(['parable', 'linear', 'linear', 'parable', 'parable', 'parable',
       'parable', 'parable', 'parable', 'parable'], dtype='<U21')
```

---

`pandas` solution:

You can also consider using `pandas` for improved readability.

```
>>> import pandas as pd                                                                                                           
>>> data = pd.DataFrame(values, index=pd.Index(x, name='x'), columns=['parable', 'linear', 'sine'])                               
>>> data                                                                                                                          
   parable  linear      sine
x                           
0      0.0     0.0  0.000000
1      1.0     3.0  0.841471
2      4.0     6.0  0.909297
3      9.0     9.0  0.141120
4     16.0    12.0 -0.756802
5     25.0    15.0 -0.958924
6     36.0    18.0 -0.279415
7     49.0    21.0  0.656987
8     64.0    24.0  0.989358
9     81.0    27.0  0.412118
>>>                                                                              
>>> data['name_of_max'] = data.idxmax(axis=1)                                                                                     
>>> data                                                                                                                          
   parable  linear      sine name_of_max
x                                       
0      0.0     0.0  0.000000     parable
1      1.0     3.0  0.841471      linear
2      4.0     6.0  0.909297      linear
3      9.0     9.0  0.141120     parable
4     16.0    12.0 -0.756802     parable
5     25.0    15.0 -0.958924     parable
6     36.0    18.0 -0.279415     parable
7     49.0    21.0  0.656987     parable
8     64.0    24.0  0.989358     parable
9     81.0    27.0  0.412118     parable
```